# How do I get the value at a specific coordinate of raster using leaflet L.canvasLayer.scalarField

Tags: leaflet

How do I get the value at a specific coordinate of raster using leaflet L.canvasLayer.scalarField, i only can obtain the value when the user "click" on map like in this code:

```
d3.text("https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/data/Bay_Speed.asc", function (asc) {
    var s = L.ScalarField.fromASCIIGrid(asc);
    var layer = L.canvasLayer.scalarField(s).addTo(map);

    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.value !== null) {
            let vector = e.value;
            console.log(vector)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/blob/a56d164975981584f6c8ca400ad5aa6c71a850f2/src/Field.js#L194

Comment: Thanks, very much, it work, i use:  'layer._valueAtIndexes' , ;-)